# How to do an event when any user updates their profile?

Tags: updates, profiles

I want to call a function, whenever any user update their profile. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if the hook [`personal_options_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) might be what you're looking for.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_custom_func' );
function my_custom_func( $user_id /* if you need that */ ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 since you basically said what I said and included example code. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I also use this hook in plugin as well?

Comment: Well, of course can you include this functionality into a plugin, as well as into a theme's `functions.php`. If I could be of help, would you mind accepting this answer so that someone having the same/a similar problem can see its solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using either the [`personal_options_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) or [`edit_user_profile_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) hook depending on what exactly you want to do. If those aren't firing when you need, you can poke around in http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/user-edit.php to find a different hook to use.

See [Justin Tadlock's tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) for more